# Pass a variable to another script

Tags: powershell

I have two PowerShell scripts.
The first script has the following code:

```
$var = "abc"    
$DIR = "C:\"
$SCRIPT_NAME = "abc.ps1"
&"${DIR}\${SCRIPT_NAME}" #execute the second script
```

If I want to pass the variable `$var` to the second script, how do I achieve that? What code do I need to put in both the first and the second script?

Answer (score 2):

**Parameters (Recommended):** Use parameters to pass values to the second script.

Step2.ps1:

```
param ($myparameter)

write-host $myparameter
```

Step1.ps1:

```
$var = "abc"    
$DIR = "C:\"
$SCRIPT_NAME = "step2.ps1"
&"${DIR}\${SCRIPT_NAME}" -myparameter $var
```

**Alternative**: You could also have used arguments `$args` (extra values not linked to a parameter). You can specify the first argument using `$args[0]`. I would however always recommend parameters as arguments needs to be in a specific order (if multiple arguments are passed) etc.

Step2.ps1:

```
write-host $args[0]
```

Step1.ps1:

```
$var = "abc"    
$DIR = "C:\"
$SCRIPT_NAME = "step2.ps1"
&"${DIR}\${SCRIPT_NAME}" $var
```

Comment: $var1 = "abc"

$var2 = "efg"
$DIR = "C:"
$SCRIPT_NAME = "2.ps1"
&"${DIR}\${SCRIPT_NAME}" $var1 $var2


$test1 = $args[0]
$test2 = $args[1]

Above code doesn't work. How to pass multiple variables? Thanks.

Comment: @tset "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. What result did you expect, and how does that differ from the result you actually got?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do what you want, two of which have already been suggested by [@FrodeF.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023817/1630171).

- Pass the variable as a (named) parameter:

  ```bsh
  # script1.ps1
  $var = 'foo'
  $dir = 'C:\some\folder'
  $scriptname = "script2.ps1"
  & "${dir}\${scriptname}" -Foo $var
  ```

  ```bsh
  # script2.ps1
  Param($foo)
  Write-Output $foo
  ```

  **This is the cleanest solution.** You have a well-defined interface and pass the variable in a clear-cut way from one script to another.

  Parameter definitions will also allow you to make a parameter mandatory (so that the script will ask the user to provide input if the parameter was omitted), require a particular data type, easily incorporate [validation routines](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/04/using-powershell-parameter-validation-to-make-your-day-easier/), or add [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847834.aspx).

  ```
  # script2.ps1
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Short description of the script or function.

  .DESCRIPTION
  Longer description of what the script or function actually does.

  .PARAMETER Foo
  Description of the parameter Foo.
  #>
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [ValidateRange(2,42)]
    [int]$foo
  )
  Write-Output $foo
  ```

  See [`Get-Help about_Function_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847743.aspx) for more information.
- Pass the variable as an unnamed argument:

  ```bsh
  # script1.ps1
  $var = 'foo'
  $dir = 'C:\some\folder'
  $scriptname = "script2.ps1"
  & "${dir}\${scriptname}" $var
  ```

  ```bsh
  # script2.ps1
  Write-Output $args[0]
  ```

  This is the second best approach, because you still pass the variable in a clear-cut way, but the interface isn't as well defined as before.
- Define the variable as an environment variable:

  ```bsh
  # script1.ps1
  $env:var = 'foo'
  $dir = 'C:\some\folder'
  $scriptname = "script2.ps1"
  & "${dir}\${scriptname}"
  ```

  ```bsh
  # script2.ps1
  Write-Output $env:var
  ```

  This is a less clean approach than the argument-based ones, as the variable is passed using a "side-channel" (the process environment, which is inherited by child processes).
- Just define the variable in the first script and use it in the second one:

  ```bsh
  # script1.ps1
  $var = 'foo'
  $dir = 'C:\some\folder'
  $scriptname = "script2.ps1"
  & "${dir}\${scriptname}"
  ```

  ```bsh
  # script2.ps1
  Write-Output $var
  ```

  This will work as well, because by using the [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847732.aspx) (`&`) the second script is run in the same context as the first script and thus has access to the same variables. However, "passing" a variable like this will easily break if someone runs the second script in a different context/scope or modies it without being aware of the implicit dependency.

  If you want to go this route it's usually better to use the first script for variable (and function) definitions only, and [dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847732.aspx) it in the second script, so that the definitions are imported into the [scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847849.aspx) of the second script:

  ```bsh
  # script1.ps1
  $var = 'foo'
  ```

  ```bsh
  # script2.ps1
  . 'C:\path\to\script1.ps1'
  Write-Output $var
  ```
- Technically, passing values via a file would be another option. However, I would recommend against using this approach for several reasons:

  - it's prone to errors due to improper permissions (could be mitigated by creating the file in the `$env:TEMP` folder),
  - it's prone to littering the filesystem if you don't clean up the file afterwards,
  - it needlessly generates disk I/O when simple in-memory operations provided by the language would suffice.