# Pass variable to subscript

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script in PowerShell with a list and a Job

```
$file_bme1 = "C:\file1.txt"
$file_bme2 = "C:\file2.txt"
$scriptList =@(
    'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\collection1.ps1'
    'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\collection2.ps1'
);
sleep -seconds 10
Write-Output "Script starting..."
foreach ($i in 1..1){
Write-Output "Loop $i"
$jobs=foreach($script in $scriptList){
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {& $using:script}
    }
$jobs | Wait-Job | Receive-Job 2>$null
Write-Output "End of Loop $i"
sleep -seconds 30
}
Write-Output "Script completed."
```

I would like to pass variable $file_bme1 and $file_bme2 to the subscripts (collection1.ps1 and collection2.ps1), but I'm having issues on how to achieve that. Any recommendation?

Comment: What is the input parameter for `collection1.ps1` and `collection2.ps1`? do they take a single string or do they take an array as input? how would you normally do this outside the job

Comment: I usually do that with named parameter, similar as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023694/pass-a-variable-to-another-script

Comment: Right, so, both scripts take 1 file at a time or you pass both files to one call? It is not clear and we can't guess what both script do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to enumerate two arrays (collections) *in tandem*, i.e. to process the first element from one collection together with the first element from another, and so on.

There is (unfortunately) [no direct way to do that](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14732), but you can use indexing:

```
# Create a second list that parallels $scriptList
$fileList = $file_bme1, $file_bme2

# Loop over the list (array) indices and pass the corresponding
# elements from the two lists to Start-Job
$jobs = foreach ($i in 0..($scriptList.Count-1)) {
  # Invoke script $scriptList[$i] with $fileList[$i] as its argument.
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & $args[0] $args[1] } -Args $scriptList[$i], $fileList[$i]
}
```